# Creating a folder from first 5 characters of filename in a batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Here's what I have:

```
C:\test\12345-test1.txt
C:\test\23456-test2.txt
C:\test\44444-test3.doc
```

I would like to have the script read the first 5 digits from the file, create a folder with those digits, and include the letter T before it.

The result after running should be like this:

```
C:\test\T12345\12345-test1.txt
C:\test\T23456\23456-test2.txt
C:\test\T44444\44444-test3.doc
```

Currently, I have this, which does the function; I just can't figure out where to put the SET command to extract the 5 characters.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
md "T%%a" 2>nul
move "%%a" "T%%~a"  
)
```

I think this needs to be added to choose only the first 5 characters:

```
set first5=%%a:~5,1%
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off

for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d /b') do (
  if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a"
)

goto :EOF

:func
set file=%~1
set dir=%file:~0,5%
md "T%dir%" 2>nul
move "%file%" "T%dir%" 
goto :EOF
```

This will process files (= no dirs) in the working directory. I also added a check to prevent the script from moving the batch file itself in case it happens to be located in the wd.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I do get "The system cannot find the file specified." errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the first five characters:

```
set first5=%a:~0,5%
```

`set` assigns the value after the `=` to `first5`. `%a%` would return the value of variable `a`, by adding the following characters you reference the range starting at character 0 and the next five ones.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am just not sure how to compile it together to make it work.  
    for %%a in (*.*) do ( 
    set first5=%a:~0,5% 
    md "T%%a" 2>nul 
    move "%%a" "T%%a" 
    )  

     Doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: If you want to access some variable, use `%varname%`, not `%%varname`. Try `echo %first5`. You never used first5 after SETting it?

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about what your code does?

Comment: Did so. As these are primarily very basic operations I recommend you to have a look at some batch-tutorials (can't reference any, sorry - have a look yourself, most look a lot like beepworld and 90's but are still fine). More information about set can be got by calling set help `set /?`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're going through the trouble to learn something, why not learn something worthwhile? In PowerShell:

```
$x = gci ; $x | % { $d = 'T' + $_.Name.Substring(0,5) ; mkdir $d ; move $_ $d } | Out-Null
```