# A batch script for creating a folder for each file

Tags: batch-file

It might be a duplicate of this but I need a little revision:
[Creating a folder from first 5 characters of filename in a batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/350434/creating-a-folder-from-first-5-characters-of-filename-in-a-batch-file)

I don't need to select the first five letters of the file. I want the folder name to be exactly the same as the file name. And I want it to happen in the folder wherever the batchscript is located. So it must detect the current folder.

Any easy way to modify the original script?

EDIT: Actually not much modification is needed. However when it creates the folders it includes the file extension. Is there a way to remove the file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `~n` includes only the filename without the extension.

You don’t even need a whole batch file, just the following line is enough:

```
for %i in (*) do md "%~ni"
```

It must be run from the target directory though, so the current directory is irrelevant because `md "%~ni"` defaults to creating the directory in the current working directory.

If you want to run it from any directory and pass it the target (e.g., create a shortcut that you can drag-and-drop folders to), then you can use this (e.g., `Files2Folders.bat`):

```
@for %%i in (%1\*) do md "%1\%%~ni"
```