# Extracting data from filename with spaces in Batch file

Tags: batch, filenames, parsing

I have a batch file that moves a list of files around by grabbing the first 6 characters from the filename and moving it to the folder containing the extracted characters. I need to take this one step further and extract the year from the filename into a variable. The problem I am having is that the naming convention for these files contain spaces. So when I run my current batch file, it only works with the first 6 characters.

I modeled my setup from here:
[Creating a folder from first 5 characters of filename in a batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/350434/creating-a-folder-from-first-5-characters-of-filename-in-a-batch-file?newreg=eef5cdaa535240869c3aeb0c0888991f)

The file names I am working with now are as such:

```
123456 - 2020 Information.pdf 
654321 - 2022 Documentation.pdf 
111111 - 2019 Additional Docs.pdf
```

I am wanting to extract the year (in the middle) into a variable, as, in addition to moving it into the account folder, we need to also be storing these files in a "catch all" folder for that year. So I want to copy the file to that folder and then have it move to the correct account folder. I currently have multiple batch files (one for each year) that I am doing this with, but would like a simplified single file, as many of the different year files are in the same folder.

I have tried a few things I found online, including setting the "usebackq" option on the FOR loop as well as adding quotes around the "set" for the variables. But the breakdown appears to happen in the FOR loop itself:

```
    for /f %%a in ('dir /a:-d /b') do (
  if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a"
)
```

In the example from the other page (linked above) after this, you have a variable of "%~1" to work with, but when I output that variable (before I do anything with it) it simply is only the first 6 characters of the filename.

So any advice on how to get the entire filename into the variable would be appreciated.

Here is my entire batch file as it is currently (with the added "year" line):

```
@echo

set scanfolder=\\mainserver\files\scans\
set accountfolder=\\mainserver\accounts\

for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d /b') do (
  if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a"
)
goto :EOF

:func

set file=%~1
set dir="p%file:~0,6%"
set year="%file:~9,13%"
copy /-Y "%file%*.pdf" "%scanfolder%%year%"
IF NOT EXIST %accountfolder%%dir% GOTO EOF
move /-Y "%file%*.pdf" "%accountfolder%%dir%" 
goto :EOF

:EOF
```

Comment: Try replacing `for /f %%a in...` with `for /f %%a "tokens=" in...`

Comment: Hmm, adding "tokens=" to the line just flickers the command window and nothing else is done. I now have `for /f %%a "tokens=" in ('dir /a:-d /b') do ...`

Comment: apologies, should be `"tokens="*` to get all tokens

Comment: Same result. I even tried ```"tokens=*"``` but that didn't work either. Just to clarify, I am working with files in a directory, not lines of text in a file. I tried reading up on the tokens option, and it sounds like it works with the text within a file. Then again, it could be referencing the data in the loop, but I am not sure about that.